# Does php run faster without warnings?

Tags: php, performance

Since PHP code will run just fine even if it's riddled with warnings and notices about undefined indexes and non-static methods being called as static, etc, the question is, if I spend the time to remove ALL notices and warnings from my code will it run **significantly faster?**

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I bookmarked an article in which the author did some benchmarks about that ; unfortunatly, it's in french... but here it is *(maybe you'll understand some parts of it)* : [Ne faites pas d'erreur](https://web.archive.org/web/20081013160647/http://www.nexen.net/articles/dossier/18638-ne_faites_pas_derreur.php)

And here are the numbers, to help people who don't read french :

- 10k notices, with `error_reporting` and `display_errors` enabled : 5,162.76 ms
- same, but with `display_errors` disabled : 136.18 ms
- same, but with `error_reporting` disabled too : 117.79 ms
- and, finally, after patching the code so it doesn't produce any notice anymore : 19.51 ms

Which means that, yes, PHP code runs faster without notices/warnings/errors, even when those are not displayed nor reported.

Derick Rethans says the same thing in this article : [Five reasons why the shut-op operator (@) should be avoided](http://derickrethans.nl/five_reasons_why_the_shutop_operator_@_should_be_avoided.php) *(quoting)* :

> **Reason 3: It's slow (part 2)**
>
> Whenever PHP generates an error
>   message internally, it's processed and
>   formatted all the way up to the fully
>   formatted message that can be
>   outputted straight to the browser.
>   Only just before it is displayed the
>   `error_reporting` setting is checked.
>   This however, is not related to the
>   @-operator exclusively.
>   The error
>   message is just always fully formatted
>   before `error_reporting` is checked—or
>   `display_errors` for that matter.

Comment: Huh, I realized after posting : this is my 1,000th answer ^^

Comment: +1 for the final test.  Notices and Warnings are your worst errors specifically because they don't force you to fix the problem right away.  Missing array indices are so easy to fix, but too seldom addressed.  Personally, I treat every Notice/Warning like it's E_FATAL.

Comment: Now, a question is whether the error checking won't cause more delay than the handler. I mean: testing for existence, etc. Don't get me wrong: I hate warnings and notices. I got recently such a project but the results above don't convince me to invest the afford.

Answer (score 8):

Depends on the amount of warnings, but the error handling in PHP is, even when hiding error messages, *relatively* expensive.

What you'd have to do to estimate the effect is profiling on C level: Install valgrind (assuming you're on Linux) and then run

```
callgrind /path/to/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```

this generates a file called `callgrind.12345` or so, load this file into an app like [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) and look for `php_error_docref0` or `php_error_cb` to see how much time was spent in the error handler.

Please mind the cachegrind and valgrind docs when doing that and mind that there are many system-dependant variables involved.

EDIT: Oh one more note: I assume that **way** more time is spent while talking to databases and similar systems. and yet another additional note: fixing notices usually makes the code more robust for future changes so it's a good idea independent from performance.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't quite call it a "significant" improvement for most cases, but running code that does not generate errors of any sort naturally runs faster than code that has to generate a stack trace every other line.

Check out: http://www.noamdesign.com/Web-Design-Blog/15-tips-to-optimizing-your-php-code/ for more information on minor optimizations you can make to your code.

In my own experience, I've found that 95% of code optimization usually deals with how you use your database.