# Error in PyroCMS: Non-static method Lex_Parser::inject_noparse() should not be called statically

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have inherited a CMS system called PyroCMS and it is showing an error. I am not familiar with this CMS so any suggestions would be welcome.

> "A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: 8192
>   Message: Non-static method Lex_Parser::inject_noparse() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
>   Filename: libraries/Template.php
>   Line Number: 285"

Here is the relevant piece of code from the Template file.

```php
// Now that *all* parsing is sure to be done we inject the {{ noparse }} contents back into the output
if (class_exists('Lex_Parser')) {
    $this->_body = Lex_Parser::inject_noparse($this->_body);
}

// Want it returned or output to browser?
if (!$return) {
    $this->_ci->output->set_output($this->_body);
}

return $this->_body;
}
```

I have searched extensively for any clue as to what might be causing this but all I can come up with is dozens of other sites with the same issue

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: are you familiar with. https://github.com/pyrocms/lex#basic-usage?

Comment: I did search github/pyrocms extensively but found nothing useful. I will take a look at the link you provided

Comment: keep in mind, that this is 5-6 years old and might not be compatable with CI 3.x or php 7.x (might use deprecated functions)

Comment: anyway, this line seems to be wrong: `$this->_body = Lex_Parser::inject_noparse($this->_body);`

Comment: Yes Vickel, that is line 285, but I have no idea how to rectify it

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846310/error-should-not-be-called-statically-assuming-this-from-incompatible-context