# Why is the last method with same name of the namespaced class not considered a constructor in PHP 5.3.3?

Tags: php, php-5.3

The history of PHP says that the older versions of PHP use the class name as a method for a constructor for the same class.

**The PHP 5.3.3 documentation says that:**

> Methods with the same name as the last element of a
>   namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This
>   change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

**Example:**

```
namespace A;

 class classOne{
   public function methodOne(){}
   public function methodTwo(){}
   public function classOne(){} //Constructor
 }

 class classTwo{
   public function methodOne(){}
   public function methodTwo(){}
   public function classTwo(){} //Constructor
 }
```

So according to this documentation, `classOne()` and `classTwo()` are not considered as constructors? What is the reasoning behind this? Can anyone tell me?

[Reference Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor)

Comment: As you have referenced, in namespaced classes it doesn't work anymore (since long time). Or am i reading this false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding why this rule applies for namespaced `classes` vs. `non-namespaced`, `PHP 5.3` introduced namespaces. If you were upgrading from an older `PHP` version, you would have non-namespaced classes to look after, potentially using the old style way of creating constructors.

They want to enforce that you are developing within modern `PHP` principles and that you are also using the new conventions. `PHP` at this point is committed to removing old-style constructors completely, which we have seen as they are deprecated in `PHP 7` and will be removed in a future version.

Finally, the reasoning behind dropping this convention altogether is that it is more error-prone. Using the DRY principles, if one was to change a class name while refactoring, forgetting to change the name of the constructor, it could have subtle and not-so-subtle repercussions.

If you are extending a class and want to call its constructor, it is also more error-prone if their parent class's name changes. For further reading:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29794401/823549

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/217876/823549.